# In a bathroom, do baseboards need to be caulked to prevent water seepage?

Tags: baseboard

Adding baseboards to my bathroom. Do I need to caulk them, especially where it meets the flooring? And if so, do I need to leave a small gap to allow the caulk something to grip onto?

Comment: Excssive water isn't good for baseboards. There isn't a need to caulk along the floor and I certainly wouldn't leave a gap if you decide to do it. You just want to keep the area along the walls as dry as possible.

Comment: What material are the baseboards made of?  Wood?  Some sort of synthetic, like PVC?  In any case, you want to 1) prevent any water from making it down to the sub floor (usually made of wood), and 2) you don't want any water to wick up under the molding or up behind it and the wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caulk it.  I wouldn't leave a gap.  I'd tape the floor and apply caulk.  People clog toilets and flood bathroom floors.  I use PVC baseboards in bathroom since they are water resistant.  MDF is horrible for water but if you caulk it and have it well painted it is possible it holds up to a few water incidents.